# MemoryCache doesn't find item I just put in there

Tags: c#, jenkins, caching, mstest

I am using mstest to test an web application (.net core 6).

My application does something like this:

```
public async Task<User?> GetUser(string key) {
   if (MemoryCache.Default.Get(key) is User user)
        return user;
   return null;
}
```

My unittest does this:

```
try {
    var username = "myTestUser";

    MemoryCache.Default.Set(username, new User(), new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2) });

    var user = await SomeClass.GetUser(username);
    if (user == null)
        Assert.Fail("user missing");
} finally {
    MemoryCache.Default.Remove(username);
}
```

now you would say 'ofcourse this works' and it does. On my local machine anyway...
But on our buildserver (latest jenkins on a windows machine) I get errors every now and then..
Today I had to build my application 3 times before this particular unittest passed.
It simply says 'user missing....

And i'm all out of idea's..

Comment: fundamentally, it should always be assumed that things can fall out of cache at unexpected moments - presumably in this case it relates to memory pressure, but: we don't need to know the reason; sometimes, you just need to hit the underlying store...

Comment: Either way, your unit tests shouldn't be relying on `MemoryCache`. You should abstract that away, perhaps use a mock to return a known value, that will make your tests less brittle.

Comment: I didn't know the MemoryCache drops data on it's own. I even read (in some other stackoverflow answer) that it explicitly doesn't do that.. So I might have made some bad assumtions based on that..

Also I can't really get information about that from MS site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0
Anyone has a better link?

Comment: It does not state it explicitly yes. But you can deduce that from the existence of the CacheMemoryLimit property or PhysicalMemoryLimit property and the description of them. And the used word "heuristics" there should trigger a "i don't want that dependency in a test".

Comment: I agree with the above comments that your tests shouldn't depend on a cache. You can easiliy register and inject `IMemoryCache` (comes with the framework too) instead to mock it in the test. That being said, to verify the cause of the problem you can try the [`RemovedCallback`](https://git.der.de:8443/projects/ITD/repos/central/pull-requests/387/overview) that is being called after cache eviction. Sneak an `Assert.Pass()` in there to hack-fix the failing tests.